# A desfragmentação do disco rígido pode auxiliar no desempenho de uma aplicação do meu servidor?

Tags: desempenho, sistema-operacional, independente-de-linguagem

Sempre escuto falar que é necessário "desfragmentar o disco rígido". Mas nunca soube especificamente os processos internos que envolvem essa operação.

Uma dúvida por exemplo é:

- Como um software consegue fazer essa operação no hardware?
- E porque os sistemas de arquivo do Linux não precisa ser desfragmentado?
- Se meu servidor onde tenho aplicações como PHP e Python tiver o disco desfragmentado, ganho desempenho?

Comment: Por curiosidade. Essa pergunta não foge do escopo do site? obs: ainda não negativei. Essa pergunta pode sim ser tratada e ser muito interessante.

Comment: Bem, gente, se foge do escopo é só fechar. Não precisamos fazer drama ;)

Comment: @durtto não temos um super user em português.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters tem como sugerir a criação de um, como ocorreu com o SOpt? Porque até então, a unica fonte éra a comunidade do hardware.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe já tentaram fazer um SuPT. Não deu certo .(

Comment: Não tenho certeza que fazer isto melhore potencialmente as aplicações como php ou python, mas provavelmente irá melhorar o uso do "storage" como ler ou gravar dados (nada que seja tão perceptível), você só sentirá diferença se antes o driver estive-se muito fragmentado. Sobre a pergunta me parece que esta no limite do escopo, mas o problema é que é uma questão extremamente ampla e uma resposta pode ou não ser correta variando conforme o ambiente que usa. No entanto não votei por fechar, pois não tenho muita certeza.

Comment: Obrigado pela sinceridada @GuilhermeNascimento ;)

Comment: Discussão relevante no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2546

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Em um disco rígido, sim, terá ganho fazendo a desfragmentação. Note que esta é uma questão lógica, nada tem a ver com o hardware. Depende só de como o sistema operacional funciona, especificamente o sistema de arquivos dele.

Em um dispositivo de estado sólido não terá ganho (talvez um pouco, mas irrisório e pagará um preço caro demais já que este tipo de armazenamento tem problemas se fizer muita escrita, e a desfragmentação faz muita escrita). Mais ainda em NVRAM.

O ganho é absurdo para aplicações que rodam em PHP ou Python, ou outras linguagens? Em geral não, mas pode haver alguns casos, só testando para saber. Obviamente estes ganhos se darão em programas que acessam muito o disco dentro de certos padrões. Acessar pouco o disco ou fazer acesso que é essencialmente randômico fará pouca ou nenhuma diferença.

A qualidade do desfragmentador conta também.

## Porque fragmenta

Resumida e simplificadamente o sistema de arquivos dos principais sistemas operacionais costuma funcionar como uma [lista ligada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102983/101) chamada de *file allocation table*. Os arquivos são divididos em páginas (*clusters*). Em geral estas páginas vão sendo colocadas em sequência no disco, coladas umas nas outras.

> Mas o que ocorre quando o arquivo aumenta? Provavelmente não tem espaço já que outro arquivo já deve ter sido gravado logo em seguida.

A página será colocada distante dali depois de outros arquivos já existentes, por isso as páginas são alocadas como uma lista ligada e não como um vetor sequencial fixo, ele precisa ter estes nós independentes para ter essa flexibilidade.

> E o que acontece se remover um parte ou todo o arquivo?

Partes do disco ficam livres (não são apagados de fato) e em algum momento essas páginas precisam ser reaproveitadas, pode caber um arquivo inteiro ali, ou não. Então mesmo na criação de um arquivo inteiro do zero pode fragmentar. Afinal, se o arquivo não cabe naquele espaço ele já precisa ser colocado em outras partes. Em tese é possível ter um arquivo tendo sempre uma página de outro arquivo intercalando.

Nem falei das escritas concorrentes de dois arquivos que podem, em algumas situações, criar uma fragmentação natural. Em geral os SOs evitam isso fazendo pré-alocação, que é uma técnica que evita fragmentação mesmo sem concorrência. O que pode ser feito manualmente quando se sabe que o arquivo tende a crescer e se beneficia de não fragmentar.

[image: Fragmentação]

## Como funciona a desfragmentação

A desfragmentação é fazer com que a lista ligada fique parecida com um vetor sequencial, ou seja, juntar todas páginas na ordem natural para o arquivo. Leia como a lista ligada funciona no *link* acima.

Obviamente nesse processo é provável que várias páginas tenham que ser relocadas para outra posição temporariamente para ceder espaço sequencial para o arquivo que está sendo desfragmentado.

Alguns fragmentadores podem fazer isso de forma mais inteligente, inclusive colocando os arquivos mais usados nas bordas do disco, onde o acesso é muito mais rápido. O perímetro da circunferência da borda é muito maior que o perímetro da circunferência do centro, então cabe mais dados, e como a velocidade de ambas é, obviamente a mesma, em um giro completo do disco lê-se muito mais dados na borda, tornando a leitura (ou escrita, claro) mais rápida (no sentido de manipular mais dados no mesmo tempo, não em terminar antes).

O acesso sequencial aos dados é mais rápido em casos assim, já que o acesso vai sendo feito de forma natural no giro do disco. Se tiver que ficar procurando onde estão as outras partes, muito giro é desperdiçado sem realizar uma operação de leitura ou escrita. Quando vai tendo fragmentação o acesso que teoricamente seria sequencial passa ser randômico.

Lembre-se que a fita magnética ou de papel era totalmente sequencial (não fragmentava, mas também não tinha flexibilidade), o HDD é semi-randômico (randômico em um eixo e sequencial em outro), e o SSD é 100% randômico (por isto desfragmentação nele não é necessária, ele se dá bem com esta forma).

## Linux

Existe o mito que Linux não precisa desfragmentar.

Primeiro, estamos falando de qual sistema de arquivos? Ele pode usar vários (na verdade o Windows também, mas ninguém usa). É a [Ext3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3)? Tem que desfragmentar sim.

O ponto positivo dela é que tem um algoritmo muito bom que organiza melhor o processo de gravação tentando coordenar melhor a ordem usada, assim a fragmentação é pequena, mas fragmenta sim.

O ponto negativo é que para desfragmentar precisa desmontar o volume (e nem é tão simples assim desfragmentá-lo. E os arquivos podem ser colocados mais próximos do centro do disco sem necessidade imediata, tornando seu acesso mais lento.

Pode haver retardamentos na alocação por causa do algoritmo, isto diminui a fragmentação, mas torna o acesso mais lento, além de aumentar o potencial de perda de dados.

É melhor na Ext4 que facilita a desfragmentação e tem técnicas mais apuradas para evitar que ela aconteça, como o mapeamento de  *clusters* e mais facilidades de pré-alocação.

> Se o sistema de arquivos não precisa desfragmentar, como resolve as questões que eu coloquei acima de arquivo que cresce ou diminui de tamanho, que precisa ser encaixado onde estava outro arquivo antes?

Só existe uma solução, ficar copiando tudo para outro local, e precisa sempre ter espaço para a cópia de integral do maior arquivo existente mais o tamanho que está sendo adicionado. Seria trágico em performance. Não existe milagre, não existe almoço grátis.

Existem *filesystems* específicas que até fazem isto, mas usam-se elas quando se sabe que estes padrões de uso de arquivo mencionados nunca são aplicados, ou são de forma controlada.

Existem outras que fazem a desfragmentação durante o processo de gravação. Ele distribui o processo ao longo das operações. Obviamente o custo de gravação de um arquivo acaba ficando maior do que se espera e o tempo passa ser não determinístico. Outras podem fazer isto sozinhas quando o disco não está sendo demandado.

Tudo é *tradeoff*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).