# Diferença entre array de char e ponteiro de char

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, memória

Criei um pequeno código de exemplo para tentar entender a diferença entre *array* de `char` e ponteiro de `char`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Person
{
    char name[256];
    char *apelido;
} person;

void insere_person_name(person *p){
    printf("insira um nome: ");
    scanf(" %s", p->name);
}

void insere_person_apelido(person *p){
    printf("insira um apelido: ");
    scanf(" %s", p->apelido);
}

void string_person(person *p){
    printf("person{nome:%s, apelido:%s}\n", p->name, p->apelido);
}

int main()
{
    person p;
    //person p = {"Fulano", "Lano"};

    insere_person_name(&p);
    insere_person_apelido(&p);

    string_person(&p);

    return 0;
}
```

Ao rodar este código percebemos que ele vai causar um erro quando executar o método `insere_person_apelido()`, se descomentarmos `person p = {"Fulano", "Lano"};` e no lugar comentarmos os métodos de inserir os dados percebemos que ele esta recebendo as informações corretamente.

Por favor gostaria de explicações para que eu possa entender as diferenças e quando utilizar um ou outro e como utilizá-los.

Comment: Só para esclarecer: O voto negativo naquela outra questão que você deletou não foi meu. Não votei contra e nem a favor. Eu até havia tentado elaborar uma resposta no dia que você postou, mas não tinha conseguido chegar a nada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, eu sei que não foi teu, pois tu havia comentado bem antes, fica tranquilo, eu deletei porque ninguém havia apresentado uma solução e eu acabei fazendo o tratamento pelo front mesmo, não sei se foi a melhor forma, mas foi a que eu achei, então achei desnecessário manter a pergunta. Mas fica tranquilo mesmo. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um *array* aloca memória no local onde ele foi declarado. Então `name` ocupa 256 bytes dentro da estrutura `Person`. Qualquer objeto do tipo `person` ocupará pouco mais que isto quando for alocado.

Um ponteiro é apenas um apontador para um endereço de memória. Ele ocupa apenas 4 bytes (em arquiteturas 32 bits) ou 8 bytes (64 bits). É só isso que vai ocupar na estrutura. Ótimo, né? Mas onde o apelido mesmo vai alocado? Nesse código vai "em qualquer lugar" que o código achar.

Uma pequena mudança resolverá o problema. Basta alocar a memória dinamicamente, aí terá um local apropriado para a *string* ficar na memória:

```
void insere_person_apelido(person *p) {
    p->apelido = malloc(256);
    printf("insira um apelido: ");
    scanf(" %s", p->apelido);
}
```

Normalmente isto teria que ser feito de um jeito um pouco melhor. Teria que liberar a memória quando `p` não sirva mais. Mas em um exemplo simples, isso não causa problemas.

Um ponteiro tem sempre que apontar para um endereço de memória. Pode ser para algo alocado estaticamente pelo código ou dinamicamente pelo [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc). Usei o segundo, mas neste exemplo simples poderia ter usado um outro *array* alocado na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) e apontar para ele.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/s9PmXt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qwavxizd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/AllocChar.c).

Em C é muito fácil pegar lixo da memória se não tomar cuidado.

Lembre-se que [o tamanho dos objetos precisam ser conhecidos em tempo de execução antes de alocar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101). Alguns precisam ser conhecidos já em tempo de compilação. Não existe mágica.

Também é importante notar que a notação de acesso à *arrays* em alguns casos se confunde com ponteiros, mas que fique claro que [*arrays* não são ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101).

O exemplo original da pergunta funcionou? Sim. Mas tá completamente errado. Por isso eu falo o mesmo que profissionais experientes e os novatos não costumam ouvir e por isso a maioria jamais se tornam experientes, mesmo com décadas programando: funcionar é circunstancial, entender o que está fazendo e produzir um código correto é a única forma correta de programar.

Parecer que funciona não basta. Tem que estar certo.

Por isso "boas práticas" são ruins, acreditar que "testar" é a solução é algo ruim também, achar que metodologias sozinhas salvam, e olhar só a superfície das coisas não leva alguém à algum lugar.

Esta pergunta é um passo na direção certa para entender o real funcionando, que em C é ainda mais importante que outras linguagens, já que ela te deixa fazer "tudo" e é problema seu saber se está correto.

Comment: Bom, este foi apenas um código de exemplo feito proposital para este "erro", pois realmente quero entender o que esta acontecendo de verdade e quando devo utilizar um ou outro, mas agora me gerou uma nova dúvida, pois como tu mencionaste no inicio, por conta de "char name[256]" qualquer objeto do tipo struct ocupará pouco mais que isso na memória, certo, isto será independente de quantos caracteres eu realmente utilizar? Ou seja, será alocado mesmo que seja em braco? E com relação a outra variável, ela não ocupara o mesmo espaço ao declarar "malloc(256)"?

Comment: Ocupa o mesmo espaço, a alocação independe do que realmente usado. E mais se precisar mais, ele vai usar, só que vai melar o próximo membro (o ponteiro) e possivelmente melar outras coisas na memória. É problema do programador resolver isto. Com o `malloc()` é a mesma coisa. Ocupará o tanto que for determinada, não que for efetivamente usado. E poderá estourar a alocação igual. A vantagem é que pode determinar o tamanho da alocação no momento da execução, Ao inés de 256 poderia ser uma variável e seu valor poderia ser determinado antes de alocar a memória, flexibilizando o uso da memória.

Comment: Creio que agora eu tenha entendido sobre a utilização deles, pois tenho em mente que no fundo tudo é ponteiro em C, te agradeço pela explicação, foi de grande ajuda, embora tenha marcado a do danieltm64, pois infelizmente só posso marcar 1, mas ambos foram importantes para o meu crescimento.

Comment: Ok. A única coisa é que o que ele explicou não se aplica à sua pergunta que usa uma estrutura. Aquilo não funciona.

Comment: Neste caso, gostaria de entender o que diferencia uma variável em uma struct, e fora dela, pois pensava que eram iguais.

Comment: Na `struct` você precisa ter o tamanho conhecido. Em circunstâncias bem específicas é possível ter uma variação, mas criação complicação, não pode ser usado universalmente e não se aplica ao seu exemplo.

Comment: Vamos ver se eu entendi bem, na `struct` quando eu defino um valor, neste caso o `char nome[256]` ele já ira alocar o espaço previamente, o mesmo aconteceria no caso de `char *apelido` e posteriormente `apelido = malloc(256)`, ou seja, ele deixa engessado na memória este espaço para ser utilizado, por isto mesmo não posso criar valores dinâmicos, salvo pelo caso do ponteiro, pois este ira alocar posteriormente, é isto?

Comment: Sim, esta é a diferença do *array*, ele sempre aloca espaço. No caso de ponteiro, o programador, tem que fazer com `malloc()`, tudo isto está na resposta. è isto. Tudo tem que ter o espaço definido para alocar. Tudo no computador, não importa a tecnologia, isto é matemática. O que dá para fazer algumas coisas se definirem no momento logo antes da alocação. Outras só dá para definir durante a compilação.

Answer (score 5):

Quando você declara um array de `char` assim:

```
char name[256];
```

o programa aloca 256 caracteres na memória principal. Quando você declara um ponteiro de `char` assim:

```
char *apelido;
```

o programa aloca o suficiente para guardar um endereço (normalmente 4 ou 8 bytes) na memória principal.

Quando você usa `name` no `scanf`, ele é tratado como apontador e a string lida da entrada padrão é armazenada na memória que foi alocada para `name`. Quando você usa `apelido` no `scanf`, ele também é tratado como apontador e a string lida da entrada padrão é armazenada na região de memória para a qual `apelido` aponta. Se `apelido` aponta para uma região de memória que ainda não foi alocada quando `scanf` tenta escrever lá, o programa aborta. Se `apelido` aponta para uma região de memória que foi alocada adequadamente (por exemplo com `malloc`) o programa funciona normalmente.

Você pode mudar a função `insere_person_apelido` para o seguinte:

```
void insere_person_apelido(person *p){
    printf("insira um apelido: ");
    p->apelido = malloc(256);
    scanf(" %s", p->apelido);
}
```

Com o código acima, toda vez que a função executar, memória o suficiente para guardar 256 caracteres será alocada e o apontador `apelido` apontará para essa região de memória, em que o `scanf` poderá deixar os caracteres lidos da entrada padrão. Se `apelido` já apontava para uma região de memória alocada anteriormente, essa antiga região de memória nunca mais será liberada e ocorrerá vazamento de memória, então cuidado com `malloc`. Outra solução seria você criar uma função que inicializa uma estrutura `person`, assim:

```
void inicializar_person(person *p){
    p->apelido = malloc(256);
}
```

Essa função aloca espaço o suficiente para 256 caracteres e faz com que o membro `apelido` de `p` aponte para essa nova região de memória. Você tem que se lembrar de sempre chamar essa função quando você instanciar uma `person`. Exemplo:

```
person p;
inicializar_person(&p);
```

Assim, toda instância da estrutura `person` começará em um estado que as outras funções que lidam com `person` poderão presumir, e a função `insere_person_apelido` poderá ser escrita assim:

```
void insere_person_apelido(person *p){
    printf("insira um apelido: ");
    scanf(" %s", p->apelido);
}
```

A função acima presume que `apelido` aponta para uma região de memória devidamente alocada, que sempre é o caso se `p` foi incializado pela função `inicializar_person`. Se no futuro você acrescentar outro apontador na estrutura `person`, você poderá adequar a função `inicializar_person` e assim as outras funções poderam presumir que o novo apontador pode ser utilizado. Contanto que você apenas utilize instâncias da estrutura `person` através de funções adequadas em vez de alterar uma `person` diretamente, o seu programa vai funcionar corretamente.

Quando você declara uma variável em C sem inicializá-la, o seu valor inicial pode ser qualquer valor. Exemplo:

```
int x = 5; // variável inicializada
int y; // variável não inicializada
printf("x = %d\ny = %d", x, y);
```

Um possível exemplo de saída desse código é:

```
x = 5
y = 19765
```

Ou seja, como `y` não foi inicializado, o seu valor inicial será qualquer lixo que estava na posição de memória em que o `y` foi alocado quando o seu programa rodou.

Logo, quando você tenta escrever na memória para onde um apontador não-inicializado aponta, você muito provavelmente vai acessar memória que seu programa ainda não alocou adequadamente. No entanto, toda string escrita literalmente no código fonte (como "Fulano" ou "Lano" no seu exemplo) é armazenada no arquivo executável do seu programa, e quando o programa roda, essa string é armazenada em uma certa região na memória principal, logo quando você atribui "Lano" a `apelido`, esse endereço é guardado em `apelido` e o programa funciona normalmente. O problema com `apelido` é quando você tenta acessar a memória para onde ele aponta e ele não aponta para uma região de memória válida, que nunca é o caso quando ele aponta para uma string que foi escrita literalmente no código fonte.

**Acréscimo:**

A partir do padrão C99 (pense em C99 como a "versão" da linguagem C que foi publicada em 1999) é possível declarar um array com tamanho variável sem recorrer a `malloc`, assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int tamanho;
    printf("Digite um tamanho: ");
    scanf("%d", &tamanho);
    char name[tamanho];
    name[tamanho - 1] = 'x';
    printf("%c", name[tamanho - 1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Esse código produz a mesma saída que o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int tamanho;
    printf("Digite um tamanho: ");
    scanf("%d", &tamanho);
    char *name = malloc(tamanho);
    name[tamanho - 1] = 'x';
    printf("%c", name[tamanho - 1]);
    free(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Antes do padrão C99, não era possível declarar um array com um tamanho conhecido apenas em tempo de execução da forma tradicional, então era necessário declarar um ponteiro normal e usar a função `malloc` para alocar o array. No entanto, a partir do C99, é possível fazer isso, mas não em estruturas. No seu caso, você tem uma estrutura que precisa guardar um apelido, e como nem todo apelido ocupa o mesmo tamanho, sugiro que você opte por usar um ponteiro normal e chamar `malloc` para alocar esse array. Se você aceitar que nenhum dos apelidos em seu programa ocupará mais do que sei lá, 20 caracteres, você pode declarar o membro `apelido` assim:

```
char apelido[21];
```

pois assim o seu código sempre gasta 21 bytes para cada apelido, mas como nenhum apelido tem mais do que 20 caracteres, seu programa não falhará. O problema é garantir isso (se você puder, beleza), e tem também o fato de que um apelido curto, de por exemplo 10 caracteres, desperdiçará espaço (50% nesse caso), então eu sugiro declarar `apelido` assim (e alocá-lo com `malloc`):

```
char *apelido;
```

Meu conselho é esse: se você não sabe quanto espaço você vai precisar para todos os apelidos (ou qualquer que seja o membro da sua estrutura), utilize um ponteiro comum e aloque o array com `malloc`. Se todos os apelidos (ou qualquer que seja o membro da sua estrutura) for ocupar o mesmo tamanho, ou se você aceitar um possível desperdício de espaço, declare o array da forma tradicional, com um tamanho fixo. Agora, se você quer que todas as instâncias da sua estrutura apontem para o mesmo apelido, sem duplicar o conteúdo do apelido em todas as instâncias da estrutura, também sugiro que você utilize um ponteiro simples e aloque o array com `malloc`. Se você quer um array cujo tamanho só será conhecido em tempo de execução e você precisa desse array diretamente dentro de uma função (e não dentro de uma estrutura como no código que você forneceu) e você tem um compilador que suporte C99, então pode simplesmente declarar o array assim:

```
tipo nome[tamanho];
```

onde `tamanho` pode ser uma constante ou o valor de uma variável.

Comment: Certo, mas considerando que internamente tudo é ponteiro em C, como eu poderia saber quando é mais indicado utilizar um ponteiro de char e fazer uma alocação de memória com o malloc e quando eu sei que criar um array de char é o mais indicado? Existe algum "sinal" para esta questão ou simplesmente vai a gosto do programador?

Comment: Acrescentei uma explicação à minha resposta, veja se ela esclarece a sua dúvida.