# Matriz de strings

Tags: c, string, matriz

Como se declara e inicia uma matriz de `strings`?

Tentei de várias formas e ainda não tive exito, eu pensei que assim iria funcionar mas não funcionou.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char matriz[2][2];
    char string1[] = "Minha string";
    matriz[0][0] = string1;
    printf("%s", matriz[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considere sempre que uma *string*  é um tipo `char *` (ponteiro para caracteres), mesmo que use um [`char *` ainda assim é um ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130792/101) (poderia usar um *array* ali em certas circunstâncias, então se você quer uma matriz de *strings*  deve usar o tipo `char *` como o tipo da matriz.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char *matriz[2][2];
    char string1[] = "Minha string";
    matriz[0][0] = string1;
    printf("%s", matriz[0][0]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rpbJfJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/icyyxyhb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/StringMatrix.c).

Comment: C e suas peculiaridades rs

Comment: O problema é com a regra de decaimento dos tipos durante a atribuição, às vezes fica confuso. 
Em matriz[0][0] = string1;, o tipo de string1 é  char []  e decai para 
char * , então vc precisa de uma variável que acomode um ponteiro de char, mesmo nunca declarando um ponteiro explicitamente.