# Qual a diferença na atribuição de uma matriz já iniciada para uma não iniciada?

Tags: c, array, string, memória

```
char nome[10];
nome = "w" //Aqui ocorre um warning, por quê isso ?

char nome_dois[10];
nome_dois[0] = "w" //  Aqui e normal,  como esperado.
```

`"w"` está em uma memoria estática?

`nome[0]` está  em uma memória dinâmica ou estática?

Quando chamo `printf("%p", "w")` me imprime um valor hexadecimal que é a representação do `"w"` então e uma constante em uma área estática?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

> `char nome[10]; nome = "w"` --- Aqui ocorre um warning, por quê isso ?

Você não está copiando o `"w"` para a área reservada para `nome`, a cópia é feita com a função [`strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). Veja mais sobre em [Diferença entre array de char e ponteiro de char](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130792/101) e outras *linkadas* sobre o assunto. O *warning*  indica que está fazendo uma operação potencialmente errada, e de fato é errada mesmo.

> `char nome_dois[10]; nome_dois[0] = "w"` --- Aqui e normal, como
>   esperado.

Normal mais ou menos, até vai funcionar, mas pode ter situação que isto estoure a memória reservado para esta *string*.

> `"w"` está em uma memoria estática? `nome[0]` está em uma memória dinâmica ou
>   estática?

Sim, `"w"` está em área (efetivamente) estática. `nome[0]` está em área automática (que sempre acaba sendo o *stack*). Veja mais em [Usar variáveis estáticas ou dinâmicas em meus códigos? O que seria mais eficiente ou melhor visto no mercado de trabalho?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/342463/101) e [Alocação dinâmica em C - alocando sem saber a quantidade total de elementos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/345055/101).

> quando chamo `printf("%p", "w")` me imprime um valor hexadecimal que é a
>   representação do `"w"` então e uma constante em uma área estática?

O que está imprimindo é o endereço(indicado por `"%p"`) de onde está a *string* e o valor é constante em área estática. nesta área tudo é constante.

Comment: na verdade era pra ser nome_dois[10] = "w" por que da certo?

Comment: Isto está sem contexto

Comment: Desculpe ser estou sendo "burro" mas veja se as minhas definições estão corretas, o identificador de uma matriz unidimensional e um ponteiro que aponta para a pilha de dados e cada elemento dessa matriz e um ponteiro que aponta para uma area estática que contém uma constante ou e um endereço que contém uma constante que foi copiada da área estatística para área automática?

Answer (score 0):

> "w" está em uma memória estática?

Sim, strings escritas "diretamente no código" são armazenadas numa área estática. Você pode usar essas strings como ponteiros ou copiando para buffers dinâmicos, por exemplo.

```
char nome[10];  
nome = "w"; //Aqui ocorre um warning, por quê isso ?
```

Em C, a inicialização da variável e a atribuição são coisas diferentes, apesar de as duas coisas serem feitas com `=`.

```
char nome[10] = "w"; // copia a string estática "w" para uma variável na pilha (ou global)
nome = "w"; // usa a string "w" como ponteiro e tenta atribuir a um array (operação inválida na linguagem, dá erro)
```

Lembre-se dessa diferença quando disserem que C é uma linguagem simples e elegante :-)

Para fazer cópias de strings depois que a variável já está declarada, use strcpy ou memcpy.

> nome[0] está em uma memória dinâmica ou estática?

Dependendo como `nome` foi declarado, pode estar numa área de variáveis globais, ou na pilha automática de chamada de funções. Esses dois são os casos mais comuns, mas na verdade pode estar em qualquer lugar, afinal, até "w"[0] é válido! (indexar uma string estática)

```
nome_dois[0] = "w"
```

Referenciar "w" no código nesta situação, como na maioria dos casos (exceto na inicialização, como visto acima), gera um ponteiro para a string estática. Se você utilizar operações de ponteiro em "w", tudo bem. Mas aqui você atribuiu o ponteiro a um char (um dos elementos do array), o que me deu a warning no GCC:

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

(ele chama o char de integer porque chars em C são como inteiros pequenos)

Portanto, lembre-se de compilar com as warnings ativadas!

```
nome_dois[10] = "w"
```

Se fizer isso, vamos ter uma combinação de pequenos erros que podem levar a um belo desastre no seu programa. O primeiro erro é o mesmo de cima, conversão indesejada de ponteiro para inteiro e o segundo erro é escrever num elemento inexistente do array (se declarado com [10], ele vai de [0] a [9] — as maravilhas da indexação iniciando com zero...)