# Array de strings e ponteiros

Tags: c, string, ponteiro, matriz

Leia os comentários no código

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(void) {
 char *nomes[2][2]; //Eu não entendo porque se eu tirar esse ponteiro * o codigo dá erro      
 nomes[0][0]="Misael";  
 nomes[0][1]="Zaes";
 nomes[1][0]="Joao";
 nomes[1][1]="Pedrao";

  printf("%s\n",nomes[0][0]); //Como um simples nomes[0][0] pode imprimir vários caracteres?
  printf("%s\n",nomes[0][1]); 
  printf("%s\n",nomes[1][0]);
  printf("%s\n",nomes[1][1]);

 return (0);
}
```

Esse código abaixo não é mais certo para armazenar e imprimir strings?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void) {
 int N,i;

 scanf("%d",&N);

 char strings[N][256]; //Eu entendo que cada "N" posições vai ter um espaço de 256 caracteres. 

 for(i=0; i<N; i++)
   {
    scanf("%s",strings[i]);
   }

 for(i=0; i<N; i++)
 {
   printf("%s\n",strings[i]);
 }     

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Algum problema no segundo código?

Comment: A questão é se você está a tentar construir um array de nomes ou um array de duas dimensões de nomes, tipo uma tabela. São duas coisas distintas. No primeiro exemplo você tem um array 2d de ponteiros para char, ou seja uma tabela com linhas e colunas de "nomes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está criando uma matriz bidimensional (2 X 2) de *strings*. Você já deve saber o que é uma *string*, conforme eu [expliquei em outra pergunta sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321313/101), mas você preferiu a resposta que não explica nada e ignorou a minha, por isso está com dúvida sobre isto. Então se voltar lá e ler novamente o que eu expliquei saberá porque tirar o `*` dá erro. Se fosse só esta dúvida, esta seria duplicata da outra.

Então você tem algo assim:

```
    |    0     |    1
--------------------------
 0  | (char *) | (char *)
--------------------------
 1  | (char *) | (char *)
```

Lembrando que esse `char *` é um endereço de memória, nada mais que isso, portanto o tamanho de cada elemento dessa matriz é 4 ou 8 bytes dependendo de sua plataforma ser 32 ou 64 bits. O texto não está aí, está em área estática.

Quando dá o `printf()` está pedindo para ele imprimir um texto que é composto de um *slot* reservado uma uma *string*, portanto um tipo `char *`, isso é definido por `%s`, é uma convenção documentação da função `printf()`, e em seguida vem um `\n` que é uma quebra de linha. Como o `printf()` faz isso é um detalhe de implementação dele, mas se formos exemplificar de forma bem simplificada e ingenuamente só para entender mais fácil, o que ele faz ali é mais ou menos isto:

```
while (*string != '\0') putchar(*string++);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Strings.c).

Ele está pegando a variável que ele recebe e varrendo ela caractere por caractere e imprimindo cada um individualmente. A condição de saída é quando ele encontrar o caractere nulo (`\0`) que é o terminador de *string*, conforme já explicado no *link* acima, neste ponto e encerra o laço de repetição. Em cada impressão ele incrementa o endereço de memória para o próximo caractere e vai mais um passo no laço. Esta é a forma básica de percorrer *arrays* na memória, sendo que uma *string* é um *array* de `char`.

Portando ele recebe o endereço de onde está a *string*, no caso específico uma área estática da memória, e varrerá essa área da memória apontada pelo elemento do seu *array* bidimensional até encontrar o tal terminador.

A diferença do segundo exemplo é que este é reservado na *stack* (também chamada de [memória automática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/280973/101)) e não na área estática da memória, através do `[256]`, até porque quando vai mudar o valor da área em tempo de execução não pode ser na área estática. Então a diferença semântica do primeiro e segundo código. Entenda sobre o uso de [memória estática, *stack* e *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/291965/101).

Tsto pode ajudar: [Qual a diferença na atribuição de uma matriz já iniciada para uma não iniciada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/301798/101) (se não for duplicata).

Se estiver difícil de entender é porque pulou etapas e precisa voltar ao básico, entender essas coisas que estou falando em primeiro lugar, não se constrói uma casa iniciando pelo telhando, precisa fazer o alicerce. Os *links* que eu passei na resposta anterior tem tudo isso, se não diretamente pelo menos dentro deles. tem que ler, todas suas dúvidas já foram respondidas antes aqui no SOpt. *Links* na internet foram criados para serem seguidos e dar mais detalhes sobre o assunto.