# Usar variáveis estáticas ou dinâmicas em meus códigos? O que seria mais eficiente ou melhor visto no mercado de trabalho?

Tags: c++, variáveis, memória

O que é melhor: Usar variáveis estáticas ou dinâmicas (usando ponteiros no caso) em meus códigos? O que seria mais eficiente ou melhor visto no mercado de trabalho?
Imagino que cada uma tem suas aplicações mais recomendadas, mas queria alguma opinião exterior. Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Isto não é uma pergunta objetiva. Depende inteiramente do caso que tem em mão, e por isso não existe nenhuma regra que seja sempre para um lado ou outro.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Comment: Sim. Foi útil, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O mercado de trabalho nada tem a ver com isso (o mercado vê outras coisas, por exemplo conceituar as coisas corretamente para entender o que está fazendo e assim produzir resultados adequados, ele não olha para um ponto específico, mas a atitude geral e capacidade da pessoa). Estou respondendo porque o núcleo da questão não parece ser este.

[Variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) não são dinâmicas ou estáticas. O mais próximo desse termo é a variável ser considerada estática porque é uma variável de classe, em oposição a ser uma variável de instância, na fundo o conceito certo é ser variável de classe, estático é um termo usado no código apenas.

O que está falando é sobre os objetos em si, estes podem ser alocados de forma estática, automática ou dinâmica.

A alocação estática é muito simples e ocorre na inicialização da aplicação. Ela não é o que você provavelmente está achando que é. O objeto já faz "parte do código".

O que provavelmente acha que é estático é a alocação automática que ocorre no que se chama [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) (que pode usar ponteiro também, é um erro associar o tempo de vida ou local de alocação com o uso de ponteiro). Essa alocação é sempre preferível porque ela custo muito barata, a liberação é automática e por isso não precisa se preocupar em gerenciar seu tempo de vida de forma complexa, entre outras vantagens.

A alocação dinâmica (ocorre no *heap* e por isso o uso do ponteiro é obrigatório já que a variável não está lá) é usada quando não tem outro jeito. Quando precisa de um tempo de vida mais longo ou menos previsível, ou ainda quando ocupa muito espaço.

Veja mais em:

- [Performance de acesso a dados na heap e stack e alocação de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101)
- [Quando devo escolher entre utilizar ou não um ponteiro ao criar um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/101)
- [O que impede um array de ser inicializado com um tamanho variável em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101)
- [O que torna um objeto elegível para ser alocado no stack?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121595/101)
- [Como o malloc() organiza a memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/254358/101)