# Convertendo um vector<struct> em C++ em C

Tags: c, c++, array, struct, vector

Eu estou tentando adaptar uma função de C++ em C puro. Eu alterei os nomes das variáveis e `structs` porque não vem ao caso.

```
typedef struct struct1 {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    string d;
} STRUCT1;

typedef struct struct2 {
    int aa;
    int bb;
    int cc;
    clock_t time;
} STRUCT2;

vector<STRUCT2> createVector(STRUCT1 str1) 
{
    vector<STRUCT2> vec;
    int var = str1.c, count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.b; i++) {
        usleep(1);
        STRUCT2 aux;
        aux.aa = 0;
        aux.bb = count;
        aux.cc = 0;
        aux.time = clock();//start times
        vec.push_back(aux);
        if (--var == 0) {
            var = str1.c;
            count++;
        }
    }
return vec;
}
```

Minhas dúvidas são:

1. `vector<STRUCT2> createVector(STRUCT1 str1)`
2. `vector<STRUCT2> vec;`
3. `vec.push_back(aux);`

Como eu passaria essas 3 linhas de código para C puro no código acima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com muito trabalho. Pelo menos se for fazer tudo na mão. Na prática você terá que criar seu próprio `vector`, que não é algo simples. Até tem como fazer uma implementação ingênua, mas nem de perto fara a mesma coisa que o `vector`. Você terá que usar o [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), mas não é só usar a função. Para ter a mesma semântica é complicado. Se puder mudar a semântica aí pode ficar mais fácil, mas a pergunta não fala nada sobre isso.

Até tem um [exemplo no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4694762/221800), mas achei a implementação bem ruim.

Pode usar uma biblioteca que tenha isso pronta. Por [sugestão do Anthony Accioly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166204/imprimindo-um-vetor-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-c-e-c-onde-errei/166214#comment342001_166204) pode usar a [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-data-types.html) ou [Gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/).

Para entender o problema leia [O que impede um array de ser inicializado com um tamanho variável em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101).

Answer (score 0):

Como C não possui containers como o `std::vector`, o jeito é usar uma array alocada dinamicamente.

```
STRUCT2 *createVector(STRUCT1 str1) 
{
    STRUCT2 *vec = malloc(str1.b * (sizeof vec));
    int var = str1.c, count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.b; i++) {
        usleep(1);
        STRUCT2 aux;
        aux.aa = 0;
        aux.bb = count;
        aux.cc = 0;
        aux.time = clock();//start times
        vec[i] = aux;
        if (--var == 0) {
            var = str1.c;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: Emoon, usei esse formato e deu certo... (em partes) Estou tendo problemas para imprimir esse vetor retornado... exemplo:

Comment: @OberdanSantos Desculpe rejeitar sua edição, mas ela alterava significativamente a resposta, mesmo que seja só um `*` a mais. Se isso fosse um errinho bobo de algo que o Emoon esqueceu, então estaria tudo bem. Mas acontece que, ao menos na minha opinião, o código não deveria compilar com o `*` e o jeito que o Emoon o deixou deveria estar certo. Casos como esse seriam melhores resolvidos por meio de conversas em comentários.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Tranquilo, entendi.