# Imprimindo um vetor... Diferenças entre C++ e C... Onde errei?

Tags: c, c++, struct, vector, printf

Estou com problemas na impressão de vetor de structs em C, em C++ ele funcionou...

Primeiro vou mostrar a versão em C com problemas (na execução pois compila sem erros)

```
CACHE cache = createCache(descricao); //chamada da main

printaCache(cache); //chamada da main
```

Agora as funções:

```
CACHE createCache(CACHEDESC desc)
{
    int i, associatividade, contador=0;
    CACHE *vec;
    vec = malloc(desc.number_of_lines * (sizeof vec));

    associatividade = desc.associativity, contador = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < desc.number_of_lines; i++) {

        CACHE auxiliar;
        auxiliar.tag = 0;
        auxiliar.index = contador;
        auxiliar.data = 0;
        auxiliar.time = clock();//start times
        vec[i] = auxiliar;
        --associatividade;
        if (associatividade == 0)
        {
            associatividade = desc.associativity;
            contador++;
        }
    }
    return *vec;
}

void printaCache(CACHE vec)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(vec);i++)
    {
         printf("%d \t %d \t %d \t %d\n",i, vec);
    }
}
```

Essas funções compilam sem erros ou warnings, mas quando executo o programa ele trava...

O código em C++ que funciona 100% é:

```
void printCache(vector<CACHE> cache){
    for(int i=0; i<cache.size(); i++){
        cout<< i<< "\t "<< cache[i].tag << " \t " << cache[i].index <<"\t "<< cache[i].time  << "\n";
    }
 } 

vector<CACHE> createCache(CACHECONFIG conf){
    vector<CACHE> vec;
    int assoc = conf.associativity, count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<conf.numLines; i++){
        CACHE aux;
        aux.valido=true;
        aux.tag=0;
        aux.index=count;
        aux.dado=0;
        aux.time = clock();//inicio dos tempos
        vec.push_back(aux);
        if(--assoc==0){
            assoc=conf.associativity;
            count++;
             } 
        }
        printCache(vec);
        return vec;
    }
```

Ambas linguagens estão usando as structs:

```
typedef struct cache{
    int tag;
    int index;
    int dado;
    clock_t time;
}CACHE;
```

Enfim, gostaria de saber o que estou errando no código C pra não obter o mesmo resultado do código C++

Comment: Eu diria para você não inventar a roda. Se o programa precisa estar em C use a [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-data-types.html) (veja [`GArray`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html)) ou [Gnulib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/), [veja [esse módlo](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/MODULES.html#module=array-list)). Implementar coleções na unha para um programa real (em oposição a um exercício), rapidamente se torna uma tarefa difícil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na [resposta a sua pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166172/101) eu disse que não era tão simples fazer essa conversão. Vai ter um monte de situação diferente que precisará de tratamento adequado. A solução que parece simples não é muito adequada. Esse código ficará um pesadelo de manutenção. Mas vamos tentar resolver um problema de cada vez, mesmo não sendo o correto a fazer.

O maior problema aí é que `size()` do `vector` não se converte para `sizeof`. O primeiro realmente dá o tamanho em número de elementos do vetor. O segundo dá o tamanho em número de bytes de um estrutura de dados conhecido em tempo de compilação. Como essa estrutura é crada dinamicamente em tempo de execução, simplesmente não tem como usar o `sizeof`. Na verdade não tem como descobrir o tamanho.

A solução ingênua seria ficar transportando o tamanho para lá e pra cá para poder ser usado. Mas isso vai dificultar todo o código. O mais correto seria fazer o que eu disse naquela resposta e criar o seu próprio `vector` onde você tenha a mesma semântica, assim poderá fazer a conversão de forma tranquila sem dor de cabeça. Ou seja, a resposta ingênua lá na [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166168/101) não deu certo, fora que ela até tinha erros e aquilo não funciona como imagina. Eu sabia que isso iria acontecer.

O certo é fazer uma estrutura completa, mas vou dar a solução só para esse problema, que parece que é o que deseja. Mas note que farei a solução mais ingênua possível, outros problemas ocorrerão mais pra frente. Como não tenho informações suficientes para testar não posso garantir que tudo esteja certo. Só posso responder em cima do que a pergunta me dá.

Normalmente quando é exercício eu nem me importo que op código não seja o mais adequado possível, em casos que parece que vai usar em algo real teria que fazer um código bem mais robusto. Mas também a solução toda é errada, então não vale o esforço de tentar fazer o certo. Esse código funcionará bem na maioria das situações, mas se acontecer alguma situação extraordinária, será uma catástrofe.

Se mais pra frente tiver que criar outros vetores de outros tipos, vai complicando mais.

Crie uma estrutura para manter o vetor com seu tamanho:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    CACHE *vector;
} VectorCache

VectorCache *createCache(CACHEDESC desc) {
    VectorCache *vec = malloc(desc.number_of_lines * (sizeof CACHE));
    int associatividade = desc.associativity
    int contador = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < desc.number_of_lines; i++) {
        CACHE auxiliar;
        auxiliar.tag = 0;
        auxiliar.index = contador;
        auxiliar.data = 0;
        auxiliar.time = clock();//start times
        memcpy(vec.vector[i], auxiliar, sizeof(auxiliar));
        --associatividade;
        if (associatividade == 0) {
            associatividade = desc.associativity;
            contador++;
        }
    }
    return vec;
}

void printaCache(VectorCache vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size; i++) printf("%d \t %d \t %d \t %d\n", i, vec.vector[i].tag, vec.vector[i].index, vec.vector[i].time);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/CacheMyVector.cpp).

A impressão de `time` provavelmente não vai resultar no que espera.

Espero quer saiba onde colocar o `free()` necessário para não ter nem vazamento de memória, nem *dangling pointer*.

Reforço que essa é a solução ingênua e que o comentário do Anthony Accioly é bastante pertinente, portanto prefira usar uma biblioteca que mnatnha uma estrutura semelhante ao `vector` do C++.