# Como faço para criar uma variável do tipo char com um tamanho indeterminado

Tags: c, c++, string

Como faço para criar uma variável do tipo char*(para armazenar um nome) com um tamanho indeterminado?

Exemplo:

```
char nome[30] = { 0 } // 30 é o valor máximo e no caso se a pessoa tiver um nome grande? que ultrapasse 30?
cout << "Informe seu nome completo: " << endl;
fgets(nome, 29, stdin);
```

Comment: Você quer criar uma string de tamanho arbitrário. Para isso, é necessário usar ponteiros. Recomendo por em uma classe de modo que você possa esconder a implementação, com métodos para aumentar ou diminuir o tamanho da string alocada conforme sua necessidade

Comment: Com `getchar` e `realloc` dá bem para fazer, mas envolve construir alguma lógica. No seu caso acho melhor definir um tamanho mais largo, como `256` por exemplo e usar apenas isso. Seria espectável ler um nome com 50 mil carateres por exemplo ? E como o ia mostrar no programa ? Analogamente repare que os bancos de dados, locais onde informações como o `nome` são guardados, tem limite na mesma, indo o `varchar` ao limite de `255` carateres. Mesmo um tipo como `text`, que supostamente representa texto ilimitado também é limitado a 64KB.

Comment: Relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente, se usa por questão de desempenho arrays de tamanhos estáticos suficientemente grandes, como 999 células. Ainda assim, em C++ tem um recurso de alto nível: fluxo (stream). Fluxos permitem adicionar valores aos poucos, sem preocupações com o tamanho (fora o suporte da arquitetura). O uso da classe `stringstream` (na biblioteca `<sstream>`) permite formar e depois gerar uma estrutura `string`, esta podendo ser vista como um `const char*`.

Em C, acho que stream teria que ser implementado a mão. Há várias formas de fazer isso. Outra opção que você tem é controlar o tempo de vida dos dados, inclusive usar blocos para limitar o tempo de vida de variáveis locais. Assim, pode criar um array de tamanho assombroso, copiá-lo para um menor e apagá-lo. Assim, por exemplo.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
int main( int argCount , char **argVector ){
   int tamanhoDoNome , indice ;
   char *nome ;
   {
      char nomeTemporario[999] = {0} ;
      cout << "Informe seu nome completo: " << endl ;
      fgets( nomeTemporario , 998 , stdin ) ;
      for( tamanhoDoNome=0 ; nomeTemporario[tamanhoDoNome++] ; ) ;
      nome = malloc( tamanhoDoNome*sizeof(char) ) ;
      for( indice=0 ; indice<tamanhoDoNome ; indice++ ) nome[indice]=nomeTemporario[indice] ;
   }
   // Agora não existem mais nomeTemporario e suas células, ficou nem a carcaça de sobra.
   free( nome ) ;
   // Agora não existem mais as células de nome, só existe a variável, ficou só a carcaça!
   return 0 ;
}
```

Alguma dúvida?

Comment: Utilizar por exemplo 999 células e no caso do nome da pessoa ser pequeno, e as outras células que restarem vão ficar reservada na memória meso sem utilizar ela? Isso não causaria algum problema no programa ou deixaria o programa um pouco lento?

Comment: Isso reserva 999 chars cada um de um byte (999 bytes, nem 1Kb) e pode ser em reserva local, ou seja, temporária em casos de funções chamadas. Se garantir que o nome da pessoa não excede um número menor, pode utilizá-lo também. É comum reservar 256 células para strings pequenas. Pode ser menos ainda...