# Erro: Segmentation fault - Alocação dinâmica de matrizes

Tags: c

Eu pretendo utilizar esta função para alocar dinâmicamente e preencher uma matriz, de tamanho indeterminado de elementos, aonde cada linha possui dois elementos apenas, ou seja, um par ordenado.

```
int **lePares()
{
    int **pares = (int **) malloc (sizeof(int *)); // Aloco uma "matriz" temporária com um par ordenado. 
    int i = 0, j;

     while (1) 
     {
        j = 0;

        pares[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int) * 2);

        while (j < 2);
        {
           printf("elemento");
           scanf("%i", &pares[i][j]);

           j++;
        }

        if (pares[i][0] == EOF) // Se o valor for o ultimo a ser lido, ele sai do loop.
        {
           break;
        }

        i++; // Conta a quantos elementos foram lidos.

        pares = (int **) realloc (pares, (i + 2) * sizeof(int *)); // Realoca a matriz com a quantidade correta de elementos lidos.

    }

    return pares;
}
```

Comment: Poderia postar o erro e onde ele acontece? Pelo titulo isso é algum ponteiro que esta perdendo a referencia, o que causa a segmentação de memória.
Veja a resposta [Confusão na pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106719/o-que-impede-um-array-de-ser-inicializado-com-um-tamanho-vari%c3%a1vel-em-c) neste outro post, talvez ela te ajude.

Comment: Em vez de `scanf("%i", &pares[i][j]);`, faça `scanf("%d", &pares[i][j]);`.