# Funcionamento do armazenamento de uma variável

Tags: memória, ciência-da-computação

Com a finalidade de entender um pouco mais o funcionamento do armazenamento de uma variável eu tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Em uma situação em que é declarada e inicializada a seguinte variável `int numero = 10;`

Pelas minhas pesquisas eu entendi que serão reservados 32 bits (ou 16 bits), mas efetivamente só serão ocupados 4 bits:

`0000 0000 0000 0000`

`0000 0000 0000 1010`

A dúvida é: *o que acontece com esses bits que "não estão" sendo utilizados?*

**Caso o raciocínio esteja incorreto, por favor me corrijam.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variável não é armazenada. Para entender melhor o que é ela já tem [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) sobre. Leia para entender.

Um objeto é armazenado na memória, e pode ser acessado abstratamente por uma variável para ficar mais fácil para o programador. Concretamente apenas está acessando um local da memória.

A declaração da variável indica que um espaço na memória é reservado, e a inicialização é que um valor é colocado lá. Um valor é o objeto.

Como isso será feito em detalhes depende da linguagem utilizada e até o contexto da variável.

O tamanho reservado depende da linguagem e o tipo específico, até mesmo de que implementação da linguagem em alguns casos. Em C por exemplo, o código da pergunta pode reservar 16 bits, menos não, por especificação. O mais comum é reservar 32 bits. Nada impede ser mais. Em várias linguagens será fixo 32 bits. Tem linguagem que a reserva é bem mais complexa e o objeto precisa de informações adicionais além do seu valor. Tem linguagem que isso acontece em certos contextos.

Quando um espaço é reservado ele é ocupado, não tem como não ocupar. A reserva serve justamente para ocupar. Não existe isso de ocupar só 4 bits, você precisa de 4 bits significativos para dizer o que pretende, o resto não serão significativos, mas eles estão lá no espaço reservado. É quase certo que eles serão preenchidos com zeros, como está na pergunta.

Se pensarmos em notação decimal e for preencher uma planilha com quadrinhos para algarismos na forma que sempre serão 6 quadrinhos para cada valor, então você terá

```
000010
```

[O computador precisa trabalhar com espaço reservado específico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101). Ou usar uma técnica sofisticado para permitir a flexibilidade, que é bem menos eficiente. No computador não podemos fazer de conta que não está ocupando espaço como fazemos na mente ou até em um papel, eventualmente. Está lá, só não é significativo. Não existe vácuo.

Isso vale para qualquer tipo de valor.

Uma *string* é um caso que tem certa flexibilidade, na maioria dos casos, isso precisa de uma certa sofisticação, que envolve [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101). Em geral para o que ela é, o custo de fazer isso não é tão alto (em alguns casos é).