# Diferença entre std::list, std::vector e std::array

Tags: array, c++, estrutura-de-dados, lista, stl

Todos são *containers* utilizados para guardas dados de forma sequencial, mas quais a principais diferenças entre eles?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Ele tem semântica igual ao *array* normal do C, mas é uma forma melhor de usar no C++ quando precisa de uma sequência de objetos de forma contígua e de tamanho fixo. Obviamente ele não decai para ponteiro como ocorre com o *array* de C, pelo menos implicitamente.

O acesso ocorre em complexidade O(1). Não pode inserir ou deletar, a não ser que crie outro `array`, mas se precisar fazer isso provavelmente ela é a estrutura errada.

Eu falo que em C++ deve-se programar em C++ e deixar de lado tudo o que existe em C. Uma boa aplicação em C++ aproveitará melhor os recursos dessa estrutura do que do *array* bruto do C, principalmente por guardar seu tamanho. Ele não deixa nada a desejar em relação ao mecanismo do C, e pode ser usado com vários algoritmos do C++.

## [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

É como um *array*, a primeira grande diferença é que ele permite mudar seu tamanho. Quando precisa mudar o tamanho há um custo de processamento, mas há técnicas para evitar que o tamanho seja mudado com a mesma frequência que a necessidade de mudança, em compensação há algum desperdício de memória quando nem toda área reservada é usada.

A segunda grande diferença é que ele é um tipo por referência por padrão. Então mesmo tendo um custo de acesso O(1) é um pouco mais lento acessar um elemento nele do que no `std:array` que não possui essa indireção para chegar nos dados. E claro pode ter custos de memória dinâmica, mas depende do alocador usado.

O acesso aos elementos pode ser feito de forma segura. O custo (complexidade) das operações (inserir e deletar) é o mesmo do `std:array`, mas tem métodos prontos para fazer por você e cuidar que tudo funcione, inclusive ele invalida iteradores se alguma operação torna seu uso inválido. Todo gerenciamento é por conta dele.

É compatível com o `std::array`.

Há a recomendação de usá-lo até que tenha um motivo para usar outra forma.

## [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

É uma [lista duplamente ligada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102983/101). Além de poder manipular o tamanho, é fácil inserir ou deletar elementos em qualquer ponto da lista. Mas para acessar seus membros tem um custo O(n), o que pode criar uma dificuldade para inserir ou deletar se não souber o ponto exato onde deve ser feita a operação, afinal ele não tem um índice em O(1).

Ela não é alocada continuamente e há uma *overhead* de memória para gerenciar os nós. O processador não gosta muito deste tipo de estrutura e algumas otimizações podem não ser aproveitadas.

Alterações na sua estrutura não afetam iteradores.

Se precisar dele como se fosse um `std::array` é necessário converter.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).