# Como inserir dinamicamente em um std::array?

Tags: c, c++, array, stl

Estou migrando da linguagem C para o C++, e quero parar de utilizar meios tradicionais da linguagem C, como o vetor da mesma.

É possível utilizando o `std::array` inserir elementos dinamicamente como no `std::vector`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parabéns, está fazendo o certo. C é C, C++ é C++.

Essencialmente não pode, essa é uma estrutura de tamanho fixo. O `std:array` é idêntico ao *array* do C, que não não permite inserir novos elementos nele dinâmica ou estaticamente. Então se deseja um substituto para o *array*, é ele, só não exija dele o que o mecanismo do C não provê. Se quer manipulá-lo dinamicamente, é muito simples, use um `std:vector`. Dependendo do caso até deve usar um `std::list` ou outra estrutura.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Relacionada: [Diferença entre std::list, std::vector e std::array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101)