# Diferença das declarações de arrays C/C++

Tags: array, c++, declaração-de-variável, vector

Qual a diferença e o impacto que cada uma dessas 3 declarações de vetor trazem para meu código?

```
int n; 
cin >> n;
int* arr = new int[n];

int n; 
cin >> n;
int arr[n];

int n;
cin >> n;
vector <int> arr(n);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Os dois primeiros estão criando um *array* bruto, aquele que era usado em C. Em código idiomático C++ não se costuma usar esse tipo de *array* a não ser pra conversar com código C ou quem gosta de misturar duas linguagens diferentes.

Na prática, o primeiro está alocando memória no *heap* ([`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)) e enquanto que o segundo está alocando memória no *stack*. Entenda a diferença em [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

O terceiro usa uma estrutura de dados típica do C++. Ela permite aumentar ou diminuir o números de elementos depois dela ter sido criada, e conta com métodos que facilitam não só estas operações como uma série de algoritmos e utilidades disponíveis na própria classe [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) ou outros componentes da biblioteca padrão ou de terceiros que usem os protocolos adotados pelas estruturas comuns da biblioteca do C++. Deveria ser o preferido sempre que possível, até que se mostre necessário usar algo diferente.

Só a segunda funciona em C.

Pode ver mais em [Diferença entre std::list, std::vector e std::array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não sei se é correto fazer essas afirmações sobre o *heap* e *stack*
 já que o padrão do C++ não garante isso. Olha as respostas deste outro tópico: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159968/declaring-array-of-int#comment7157068_6159973

Comment: Estou dando uma resposta prática o que acontece na realidade em todos os compiladores hoje, no passado e é o que acontecerá no futuro a não ser que haja uma revolução que nunca ninguém cogitou, oque certamente trará um estardalhaço tão grande que que quase tudo o que foi dito antes será invalidado. Estou apenas considerando a remota hipótese. Na sua resposta também tem termos inadequados, mas nem por isso ela está errada ou confunde as pessoas para todos efeitos. Tem situação para dar resposta baseada na especificação, tem situação para explicar em linhas gerais.

Comment: Lá nos comentários apontados estão falando o quanto é pedante se apegar a isso em algo tão simples. A diferença é que a resposta que você copiou não apareceu ninguém pedante para reclamar.

Comment: Só deixando claro que não quis desmerecer sua resposta. Justamente por isso que eu disse que nem sabia se era correto fazer essas afirmações (em outras palavras, se é que a vale a pena se atentar à essas míseros detalhes). Perguntei mesmo por não ser um membro experiente e, assim,  qualquer ensinamento é válido.

Comment: Além de que a resposta não foi uma cópia pura e burra. Foi feita uma adaptação enxuta e dado os devidos créditos.

Answer (score 6):

Primeiramente, as informações fornecidas aqui foram retiradas [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4984228/4648005) (em inglês) sobre o uso de arrays em C++. Vale a pena checar para informações mais completas.

**Array Automática**

```
int arr[n];
```

As arrays automáticas (arrays que normalmente ficam no *stack*) são criadas cada vez que o fluxo de controle passa pela linha de código onde ela foi definida. Ela é automaticamente desalocada quando o fluxo de controle alcança o fim do escopo onde ela foi criada.

Nota-se que a variável criada armazena o endereço para o primeiro elemento da array.

Edit: colocando a representação em ASCII.

```
                 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  
                 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                   ^
                   |
                  arr
```

**Array Dinâmica**

```
int* arr = new int[n];
```

Array dinâmico não possuí nome, sendo assim, o único modo de acessa-lo é através do ponteiro. Em C++ eles são criados usando a sintaxe `new T[size]` (onde T é o tipo do array) que vai alocar o espaço necessário na memória e retornar um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento. Também pode ser chamado de array anônimo.

Eis uma representação em ASCII que descreve o funcionamento na memória, em tempo de execução, de um array dinâmico com 8 elementos.

```
                 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
(array anônima)  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  (new int[8])
                 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                   ^
                   |
                   |
                 +-|-+
       int* arr  | | |                       
                 +---+
```

É importante ressaltar que após terminar de usar um array anônimo, ele deve ser desalocada para devolver a memória para o sistema operacional, caso contrário vai acontecer um vazamento de memória (*memory leak*).

```
delete[] arr;
```

**Vector**

A classe *vector*, que vem por padrão no C++ (veja [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library)), é uma alternativa à representação de array primitivo (como as duas anteriores). Ela vem com algumas funções extras, além de ser dinamicamente alocado, o que permite acrescentar ou remover elementos mesmo após ser declarada.