# Quando alocar memória dinamicamente?

Tags: c++, memória, alocação, gerenciamento-de-memória

No C++ você pode declarar um objeto ou variável facilmente assim:

```
tipo_da_variável nome_da_variável;
```

Esse tipo de declaração é o mais fácil de usar, mas também pode-se usar o `new` para alocar memória dinamicamente e depois desalocar com delete.

É verdade que alocar dinamicamente objetos deixa o programa mais rápido, isto é, faz ele ocupar menos memória e CPU?

Devo sempre alocar dinamicamente objetos?

Se a resposta para essas 2 perguntas acima for não, Então poderia exemplificar alguns casos que o uso de memória dinamicamente alocada é justificável? Ou me explicar qual a utilidade de alocar dinamicamente a memória?

Eu ouvi falar que alocar memória dinamicamente é algo que deve ser feito quando nós não sabemos o quanto de memória iremos precisar, mas eu também não entendi direito esse argumento, afinal meu compilador aceita sem erros o código:

```
int num1;
cin >> num1;
char palavra[num1];
```

No código acima, o tamanho do *array* vai depender do valor que o usuário digitar, ou seja, de inicio, não sabemos o quanto de memoria que o programa vai utilizar e mesmo assim, não foi necessário o uso de `new` + `delete`

Comment: Os objetos "pre-criados" em QT são sempre alocados dinamicamente, para acessá-los se usa "->" e não "."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `tipo_da_variável nome_da_variável;`
>
> Esse tipo de declaração é o mais fácil de usar

Sim, mas está errado. Não inicializar um valor é um erro.

Essa forma chama-se alocação automática.

> É verdade que alocar dinamicamente objetos deixa o programa mais rápido

Não, de forma geral é o oposto, deve-se evitar a alocação dinâmica o máximo possível, sem causar outros problemas.

> faz ele ocupar menos memória e CPU?

São coisas distintas, mas a alocação dinâmica sempre consumirá mais memória, invariavelmente. O trabalho para alocar costuma ser monumental comparado com a alocação automática. E se não for, a liberação será monumental. Não dá para afirmar categoricamente porque C e C++ deixam você gerenciar a memória de maneiras diferentes.

> Devo sempre alocar dinamicamente objetos?

Não, é muito mais complicado gerenciar isso.

> poderia exemplificar alguns casos que o uso de memória dinamicamente alocada é justificável?

Acho que isso já está respondido em diversas perguntas:

- [Performance de acesso a dados na heap e stack e alocação de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101)
- [Quando devo escolher entre utilizar ou não um ponteiro ao criar um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/101)
- [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)
- [Diferença das declarações de arrays C/C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202826/101)
- [char[] ou *char malloc?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141975/101)

> afinal meu compilador aceita sem erros o código

Funcionar é diferente de estar certo.

[image: Carro Fiat 147 caindo aos pedaços trafegando pelas ruas]

> No código acima, o tamanho do *array* vai depender do valor que o usuário digitar, ou seja, de inicio, não sabemos o quanto de memoria que o programa vai utilizar e mesmo assim

Nenhum problema, pode fazer alocação automática definido em tempo de execução, isto não faz a alocação ser dinâmica.

- [Variáveis declaradas dentro de blocos ou subprogramas são alocadas dinamicamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/280973/101)
- [O que impede um array de ser inicializado com um tamanho variável em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101)

Answer (score -4):

É importante lembrar que será gerado o código objeto. É possível fazer essa análise. Tenho lido bastante sobre arquitetura de jogos digitais, inclusive existe um livro escrito pelo "lead programmer" da reconhecida Naughtydog, no qual ele fala alguma coisa sobre isso, principalmente quando ser vai desenvolver para consoles.

Ponteiros pode te dar mais flexibilidade nas técnicas e métodos de codificação, talvez.

Comment: Em que isso responde os questionamentos apresentados na página?