# Quando realmente usar malloc() e/ou calloc()?

Tags: c, memória, malloc

Minha dúvida se dá pelo fato de estar aprendendo com exemplos banais(ao meu ver), como em: `int *ptr;  ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));`

Me parece inútil alocar um espaço de um inteiro para um ponteiro do tipo inteiro, ele já não faz isto sozinho?

Quando de fato eu utilizo estas funções de alocação dinâmica de memória?
Se puderem dar exemplos, seria de grande valia.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Podia ter feito isso que é mais fácil, né?

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/UseMalloc.c).

Então me parece que o maior problema é estar fazendo códigos sem entender bem o que está acontecendo ali.

Não podemos afirmar sem um contexto maior se isso é necessário mesmo. É até possível para um exercício muito básico só para mostrar o `malloc()` em ação faz algum sentido, mas para uso em aplicação real realmente não deveria ser usado na maioria dos casos.

Existe algum motivo para alocar o inteiro no *heap*? É improvável. O tamanho dele é pequeno, e se o dado sobreviver ao tempo de vida da função que ele é criado o mais fácil é retornar esse valor ou devolver através de um parâmetro por referência, mas não alocar dinamicamente. Alocar com `malloc()` te obrigará em condições normais dar um `free()`, quem receber este valor deverá cumprir o contrato de liberação. Não compensa para algo tão simples.

Exemplos de casos e motivos para usar estas funções já foram respondidas:

- [Quando alocar memória dinamicamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/291965/101)
- [Performance de acesso a dados na heap e stack e alocação de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101)

Answer (score 0):

## Introdução

Durante o desenvolvimento da linguagem C (ou do C++) precisaremos um dia usar o `malloc`, mas quando? Supondo, que você cria um programa para receber dados pessoais e numa parte precisar inserir seu nome.

Por exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char nome[80]; //amazena nome

int main()
{
    printf("Insira seu nome: ");
    scanf("%s", nome);

    printf("\n\nNome: %s", nome);

    return 0;
}

//Saída

//Insira seu nome: Algum nome
//Nome: Algum
```

O exemplo acima mostra a entrada do nome, caso eu colocar meu nome: João Paulo, apenas sairá João porque no Array de `char` teria o espaço do nome como `João\0Paulo`. Caso se usasse:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char nome[80];

int main()
{
    printf("Insira seu nome: ");
    gets(nome); //Apenas é um exemplo usando gets mas não use muito pode causar o estouro do buffer.

    printf("\n\nNome: %s", nome);

    return 0;
}

//Saída

//Insira seu nome: Algum nome
//Nome: Algum nome
```

Nessa parte temos o nome sendo exibido todo. Mas o que acontece? No array de `char` sobra ainda espaços nas posições o que foi alocado na memória, o que esses espaços sem uso estaria tendo um desperdício. Para resolver isso podemos usar o `malloc`.

## Uso do `malloc`

O `malloc` faz a "Alocação Dinâmica na Memória", isto é, aloca na memória uma parte a ser usada caso no exemplo acima tiver alocado `nome` não teria desperdício.

`void* malloc (size_t size);`

Como o `malloc` tem o retorno `void` deveremos fazer um typecast para converter `void` em `char`. Veja a seguir:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* nome; //note que agora o nome é um ponteiro.

int main()
{
    nome = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) + 1); 
//podemos usar o sizeof para receber o tamanho de char e acrescentar +1 para ter um tamanho recomendado

    printf("Insira seu nome: ");
    gets(nome); 

    printf("\n\nNome: %s", nome);

    free(nome);
    return 0;
}

//Saída
//Insira seu nome: Algum nome
//Nome: Algum nome
```

No final note que temos `free` no final, é usado para liberar a memória alocada, quando não precisar mais da variável, use o `free` para deixar a memória livre. Por isso eu recomendo o `malloc`.

## Referências

[`malloc` C++ Reference](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)

[`free` C++ Reference](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/)