# Por que aceita valores além do tamanho do vetor?

Tags: c, array, c++

```
 INT vetor[3];
 vetor[0] = 110;
 vetor[1] = 12;
 vetor[2] = 30;
 vetor[3] = 13;
 vetor[4] = 1;

  Cout <<   vetor[0];
  Cout <<   vetor[1];
  Cout <<   vetor[2];
  Cout <<   vetor[3];
  Cout <<   vetor[4];
```

Resumindo: eu disse que meu vetor tem tamanho 3. Mas eu dei 5 valores para o meu vetor. A questão é, tu sabe por que ele vai executar e mostrar os valores dos outros? Por que o programa exibe valores que não fazem parte do vetor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E porque não aceitaria? De uma certa forma em C [*arrays* são ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101), não exatamente, mas quase. Então ele pode acessar toda memória disponível. É problema do programador não deixar isso acontecer.

Falei em C e de fato a pergunta tem a *tag*. Mas como C++ é compatível com C, vale também. O que muita gente não entende é que C++ prefere formas mais abstratas, mais de alto nível, que encapsule verificações de segurança e não deixa fazer isso. O *array* bruto do C que, na verdade é um ponteiro, nem deveria ser usado em C++, [tem estruturas melhores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101).

Então `vetor[4]` na verdade é o mesmo que dizer `*(vetor + (4 * sizeof(int))`. O que impede ser 4000 no lugar do 4? Nada. Se der um valor dentro da memória virtual, é válido. Obviamente está corrompendo memória.

Se quer algo mais seguro, só use as partes seguras do C++, e passe longe de C, ou vá para uma linguagem que dê segurança sempre, como Java ou C#, só para ficar nas *mainstream* que mais se aproximam de C++. C e C++ é para quem quer grandes poderes e podem ter grandes responsabilidades.

Comment: Bem esclarecedor. Muito obrigado, cara. Eu to aprendendo c++ pq ta sendo dado na aula de Estrutura de dados na facul. Valeu pelas dicas de uso da linguagem!

Answer (score 0):

Entenda que você tem que tomar cuidado quando for indexar contêineres. O que pode acontecer quando você tenta acessar elementos fora dos limites da variável depende de alguns fatores. Por que você está tentando acessar uma parte desconhecida da memória do computador isso pode gerar consequências devastadoras desde gerar valores aleatórios até levar seu programa ao crash.
Quando trabalhar com limites de variáveis é recomendado  criar uma variável constante para checar se está tentando acessar algo ilegal ou não.

```
...
const int MAX_INDEX = 4;
if (i < MAX_INDEX + 1){

    vector[i];

}
else{
    cout << "Já avisei que vai dar mer** isso ae";
}
...
```

Comment: Entendi. Valeu pela informaçao. Foi super util mano! ♥