# Como pegar o length de um char array?

Tags: c, array, c++, string, sizeof

Como faço para pegar o tamanho de um conjunto de `char` (`char**`)? Da forma que eu estou tentando está me retornando sempre o valor 4.

```
const char* opcSalgados[] = { "Pastel", "Mini pizza", "Coxinha", "Pao de queijo", "Pao de frango com queijo", "Pao de carne" };

void ImprimeMenu(const char** menuOpc)
{
    int Length = sizeof(menuOpc[0]) / sizeof(char); // Sempre me retorna o valor 4, deveria me retornar o valor o 6
    printf("Length: %i\n", Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        printf("%i - %s\n", i + 1, menuOpc[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível saber o tamanho de uma array passada como argumento para uma função utilizando templates e dedução de tipos:

```
template <size_t N>
void imprimeMenu(const char *(&menuOpc)[N])
{
  int Length = N;
  printf("Length: %i\n", Length);

  for (int i = 0; i < Length; ++i)
    printf("%i - %s\n", i + 1, menuOpc[i]);
}
```

Perceba como o parâmetro difere com o seu:

```
template <size_t N>
void imprimeMenu(const char *(&menuOpc)[N])
```

Neste caso, temos um parâmetro `menuOpc`do tipo *referência para uma array de `const char *` de tamanho fixo `N`*. Ao passar sua array `opcSalgados` para a função (como mostrado a seguir), esse template irá deduzir partes do tipo do parâmetro que são sabidos na hora da compilação pelo compilador.

```
imprimirMenu(opcSalgados);
```

Então, dado um tamanho qualquer `M` de uma array, a dedução de tipo concluirá que o valor de `N` necessita ser igual a `M`, para que então a instância da função template seja um candidato apropriado para os tipos dos argumentos.

É possível simplificar esse código usando o contêiner [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), que é efetivamente uma array de tamanho fixo, porém com uma interface melhor:

```
std::array<const char *, 6> opcSalgados = {
    "Pastel", "Mini pizza",
    "Coxinha", "Pao de queijo",
    "Pao de frango com queijo", "Pao de carne"
};

template <size_t N>
void imprimeMenu(std::array<const char *, N> menuOpc)
{ /* mesma implementação… */ }
```

A desvantagem de usar `std::array` é que o seu tamanho precisa ser especificado no parâmetro de template (como visto no código: `std::array<const char *, 6>`). Se o seu compilador suporta C++17, esse problema vai embora com a nova funcionalidade dos [guias de dedução](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides):

```
std::array opcSalgados = {
    "Pastel", "Mini pizza",
    "Coxinha", "Pao de queijo",
    "Pao de frango com queijo", "Pao de carne"
};
```

Os parâmetros de template do `std::array` são deduzidos automaticamente pelos argumentos passados ao construtor.

Em todo caso, quando você sabe o tamanho fixo da array (seja uma array primitiva, ou o contêiner `std::array`), é possível utilizar o laço `for` [baseado em intervalos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (ou *Range-based for loop*) a partir de C++11:

```
template <size_t N>
void imprimeMenu(const char *(&menuOpc)[N]) // ou std::array<const char *, N>
{
  std::printf("Length: %zu\n", N);
  int i = 1;
  for (auto opcao : menuOpc)
    std::printf("%i - %s\n", i++, opcao);
}
```

Onde `auto` será deduzido para o tipo dos elementos de menuOpc (neste caso, `const char *`). Essa variação do `for` garante que você nunca terá problemas como acessar índices fora do tamanho da array etc.

Se for preciso passar outras arrays com tipos de elementos diferentes, basta introduzir mais um tipo genérico nos parâmetros do template e usá-lo no lugar de `const char *`:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void imprimeMenu(T(&menuOpc)[N]) // ou std::array<T, N>
```

Note, porém, que agora a implementação precisa atender a qualquer tipo que for deduzido para `T`:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void imprimeMenu(T(&menuOpc)[N]) // ou std::array<T, N>
{
  std::cout << "Length: " << N << '\n'; // Aqui.
  int i = 1;
  for (auto opcao : menuOpc)
    std::cout << i++ << " - " << opcao << '\n'; // Aqui.
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou corretamente o seu exemplo. Tenho uma pergunta, é possível utilizar, mais de um template nesse caso? No caso para uma variável diferente, que pode ser vários tipos(double, float, int, long, const long).

Um exemplo do que eu estou tentando fazer(está errado o exemplo), caso não tenha ficado claro: https://paste.ofcode.org/343rbSDDTse4zxafLW7sVRy

Comment: @cYeR Você pode introduzir mais um tipo genérico nos parâmetros do template e usá-lo no lugar de `const char *`. Editarei a resposta conforme.

Comment: Obrigado, implementei nas minhas funções conforme o seu exemplo e funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

O compilador só sabe o tamanho do *array* no escopo dele, em outro escopo ele não consegue saber e tem que passar o tamanho por parâmetro.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ImprimeMenu(char *menuOpc[], size_t length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) printf("%i - %s\n", i + 1, menuOpc[i]);
}

int main(void) {
    char *opcSalgados[] = { "Pastel", "Mini pizza", "Coxinha", "Pao de queijo", "Pao de frango com queijo", "Pao de carne" };
    ImprimeMenu(opcSalgados, sizeof(opcSalgados) / sizeof(opcSalgados[0]));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/tWvOcm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xbaknwrj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/ArrayLengthParameter.c).

Comment: Eu sei que passando o argumento funciona perfeitamente, o que eu estou tentando fazer é calcular dentro da função, não tem como fazer esse cálculo dentro da função? Acho que o código ficaria muito mais limpo.

Comment: Não tem. Algumas pessoas criam uma abstração para o *array* que acompanha o tamanho, assim não precisa de mais um parâmetro. Na verdade o uso de *array* desta forma é pouco usado, isso funciona mais em exercícios. Ele é mais um alocador simples do que uma estrutura de dados, embora dê para usar assim também.

Comment: Não tem uma outra solução então? Talvez utilizando a std::vector(Método size)? Estou tentando diminuir o máximo de argumentos pois a função original(essa foi apenas um exemplo) já tem muitos argumentos o que acaba sujando o main.

Comment: Você não colocou a linguagem e pelo código parece ser C. Se for C++, não só pode, como deve ser `Vector` ou outra estrutura mais alto nível, e o *array* do C só usar como alocação ou otimização extrema. Mesmo quando não precisa tudo do `Vector` e precisa mais performance (ainda que já seja praticamente igual a outras estruturas mais simples), tem o `Array`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101

Comment: E como seria para passar para um std::vector? Seria mais ou menos assim?

https://paste.ofcode.org/JNWkGS9DdJQHG8bgzTymts

Comment: Não, em C++ praticamente não se usa `char *`, usa `string`. Além disso, dentro da normalidade, se alocaria no *heap*  e não no *stack*.