# Como copiar um array de struct para outro igual?

Tags: array, c++, struct

Tenho 2 arrays feitos de uma `struct`:

```
struct events {
    string Kind;
    int Time;
    int DurVal;
    int Chan;
};

events e1[100]
events e2[100];
```

Como posso fazer uma cópia integral do array `e1` para `e2` em um simples comando?

Comment: A resposta [dessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137953/is-there-a-function-to-copy-an-array-in-c-c) pergunta parece ser o que você procura

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Já que está usando código que só deveria usar em C e não em C++, poderia usar uma função de C:

```
memcpy(e1, e2, sizeof(events) * 100);
```

[Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy).

Ou poderia usar uma função do C++:

```
copy(begin(e1), end(e1), begin(e2));
```

[Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Ou na mão:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < 100; i++)  e2[i] = e1[i];
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Copy.c).

mas eu usaria um [`vector` ou `array`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101) que é mais a cara de C++ e é mais seguro e mais rápido em muitos casos.