# Sort em C++ não mostra o valor correto de entrada

Tags: c++, classificação

Fiz um código para ler 3 valores, e com o `sort()` ele ordena os valores em ordem crescente e logo abaixo mostra os valores de entrada. Por Exemplo:-14 21 7 ele ordena certo mas na saída mostra -14 7 21 //  **21 21 7** sendo que era pra ser -14 7 21.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int numero[2],ent[2];

int main(){

    cin>>ent[0];
    cin>>ent[1];
    cin>>ent[2];
    numero[0]=ent[0];
    numero[1]=ent[1];
    numero[2]=ent[2];

    sort(numero,numero+3);


    cout<<numero[0]<<endl<<numero[1]<<endl<<numero[2]<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<ent[0]<<endl<<ent[1]<<endl<<ent[2]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Em vez de `numero[2],ent[2];` não seria `numero[3], ent[3];` ?

Comment: `int array[numero];` o `numero` indica a quantidade de casas não qual é a ultima. Logo `int numero[2];` cria um array com 2 casas e não 3.

Comment: Deu certo era so o numero de arrays mesmo. Obrigado a vcs:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe uma diferença semântica importante entre o `[2]` usando em dois lugares diferentes. Sintaxe é algo que pode se repetir com significado diferente. É como um "leve isto para mim" e "isto é leve para mim".

Na primeira linha de código efetivo está declarando duas variáveis, ou seja, está dizendo para o compilador reservar espaço para duas [variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), uma que será chamada no código dali pra frente de `numero` e a outra de `ent`. Está dizendo que o espaço reservado deverá ser considerado o tamanho do tipo que suporta um `int` e que precisa exatamente 2 posições de memória que cabe este tipo em cada das variáveis, portanto é um *array*, um vetor.

Aí mais abaixo usamos a sintaxe de nome da variável com o mesmo `[2]`, mas agora também com `[0]`, `[1]`. Ora, se acessei o índice 0, e o 1, e o 2, estou acessando 3 índices diferentes, 3 elementos desse *array*. Mas eu reservei 2! Tem problema aí.

Se o primeiro elemento é 0, como a matemática nos ensina, o segundo é 1, para termos um elemento 2 precisamos ter 3 elementos. Então a declaração da variável está errada, lá precisa ser `[3]`.  Pode parecer esquisito, mas tem todo o sentido.

Se eu mandar você contar até 9 começando pelo primeiro número inteiro positivo conhecido da matemática, você conta 10 números.

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Conta aí, tem 10.

Aproveitei de organizei melhor o código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numero[3], ent[3];
    cin >> ent[0];
    cin >> ent[1];
    cin >> ent[2];
    sort(numero, numero + 3);
    cout << numero[0] << ", " << numero[1] << ", " << numero[2] << endl ;
    cout << ent[0] << ", " << ent[1] << ", " << ent[2];
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zGn8w4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/iilorxkr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/Declaration.cpp).

Uma última note é que não costuma-se usar *array* do C em C++. Para isto tem estruturas melhores: [Diferença entre std::list, std::vector e std::array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101).