# C++ - Qual a diferença de usar tipos fixos do C++ e typedef de um tipo?

Tags: c++, tipagem

Alguns dias atrás estudando sobre emulação me deparei com uma pergunta no stack overflow em inglês sobre a emulação do CHIP8, e uma das resposta mandava não usar arrays de C como por exemplo `int i[12]` em vez disso usar `std::array` por ser um tipo fixo, isso me deixou um pouco confuso sobre o que seria um tipo fixo, outro exemplo seria um tipo de byte que normalmente as pessoas criam com `typedef unsigned char BYTE`, em C++ tem o equivalente `std::uint8_t` só que abrindo sua definição no visual studio me deparei com isso `typedef unsigned char      uint8_t;`. Então qual é a diferença de usar o tipo declarado do C++ ou usar o seu próprio tipo definido pelo usuário se ambos são os mesmos?

Comment: Em relação ao `std::array` ele é meramente um *wrapper* sobre um array clássico do C com que lhe permite facilmente passar para funções e continuar a usar coisas idiomáticas do C++ como *foreach* sem perder informação sobre o tamanho do array. Acaba por facilitar bastante, sem nenhuma desvantagem significativa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parece que a questão resume-se a "quais são as vantagens de usar tipos fixos da biblioteca padrão (e.g., `std::uint8_t`) em vez dos tipos não fixos (e.g., `unsigned char`)."

Bom, as vantagens são (a lista a seguir não é exaustiva):

- **O tamanho em bits permanece o mesmo em qualquer ambiente.** Você sabe que um inteiro `std::uint8_t` sempre terá 8 bits, independente de qual ambiente (i.e., a plataforma) o código é compilado e executado. Já no caso de tipo como `char`, sua única garantia é que `sizeof(char) == 1`, e que `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short)`, mais nada. Não há informação sobre o tamanho em bits desses tipos, e eles podem variar de ambiente para ambiente. Esse é o problema número um que tipos fixos resolvem. A implementação desses tipos pode aproveitar-se dos tipos normais, como você já observou. A implementação não importa, o que importa são as garantias e implicâncias dos tipos de tamanho fixo. Addendum: esses tipos de tamanho fixo da biblioteca padrão de C++ são opcionais, então é possível que uma implementação não forneça-os (na prática é improvável hoje em dia).
- **Todo mundo conhece esses tipos e sabe de suas implicâncias.** Já que esses tipos fixos estão na padronização de C++, assume-se que o programador conhece seus casos de uso, implicâncias e comportamentos. Se o programador define um novo tipo, outro programador não saberá de sua existência, portanto precisa aprender sobre todos os pontos que listei. Isso cria fricção desnecessária, pois tipos já conhecidos já existem na padronização justamente por isso.
- **Problemas específicos necessitam de tipos específicos.** O tipo `std::size_t` é usado para guardar todos os possíveis valores de `sizeof` em um ambiente. O tipo `std::ptrdiff_t` é o tipo resultante do resultado de subtrair dois ponteiros, e é usado para aritmética de ponteiros e para indexação de arranjos (array indexing). O tipo `std::max_align_t` tem a propriedade de ter seu alinhamento tão grande quanto de qualquer outro tipo escalar. O tipo `std::byte` representa valores cru de bytes. O tipo `std::intmax_t` é o tipo de maior tamanho em bits. O tipo `std::int32_t` assegura ter 32 bits de tamanho, não tem *padding* e usa *2's complement* para números negativos. Enfim, cada tipo desse tem suas implicâncias, casos de uso etc.

Você pode ver todos os tipos de tamanho fixo aqui: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint. Alguns outros tipos estão aqui: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstddef

Answer (score 6):

<strike>Sem ver o contexto fica um pouco complicado responder, inclusive porque é comum a pessoa que está explicando o que leu ter interpretado errado.</strike>

<strike>Eu acredito que esteja só falando de um tipo *array* com tamanho fixo, como é o *array* do C. Seria uma oposição a um *array* que pode ser expandir se necessário. Pode ver mais em [Diferença entre std::list, std::vector e std::array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101).</strike>

A pergunta ficou bastante confusa e o que parecia perguntar não era bem o que se mostrou depois do comentário dar um contexto. A informação fica aí ainda porque pode ser útil para alguém mas o que foi perguntado era outras coisa. No texto que foi usado para gerar a dúvida não tem o termo *fixed type* (tipo fixo) como mostrado na pergunta, ele fala de tipo de tamanho fixo, que é bem diferente, inclusive o fato de ter *array* na pergunta aqui nada tem a ver com a dúvida, apenas era sobre *array* na pergunta lá no Code Review SE. Fomos induzidos a erro.

A dúvida é sobre os tipos que tem a quantidade bits garantida. Original em C os tipos primários de dados eram especificados apenas com tamanho mínimo e cada implementação do compilador da linguagem C poderia escolher o tamanho real de acordo com a arquitetura que ele iria gerar o código, o que poderia dar melhor eficiência. Com o tempo viu-se que em muitos casos seria interessante ter tipos onde se sabe o tamanho exato a ser usado. C e C++ adotaram isto, mas o padrão ainda ficou o tipo de tamanho exato não especificado antecipadamente. Então estes tipos que vieram depois na linguagem são chamados de tipos de tamanho fixo.

Não é recomendado usar `typedef` em C++ moderno, é melhor usar `using` que o compilador está melhor preparado, `typedef` ainda funciona por causa do legado. neste contexto ele é um apelido de tipos.

Normalmente usa-se alias de tipo por uma questão de legibilidade (mostrar a intenção) e para dar alguma flexibilidade, assim você usa um tipo abstrato e dependendo do `include` que usar o concreto pode ser diferente. Este exemplo ser o mesmo é uma coincidência. Em programação coincidências não contam, por isso não conte com elas, este contexto é diferente de outros, está olhando a foto e não o filme.

Não se recomenda mais usar ALL_CASE de notação para nada em C++.

Comment: Essa minha dúvida surgiu ao ler esta resposta: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/148802

Comment: @SamuelIves com o contexto vi que a pergunta nada tem a ver com o que você perguntou. O que fica mais estranho pelo fato de ter aceito a outra pergunta que o foco é na parte que nada tem a ver com o que quer saber de fato. Preciso pensar se não é o caso de fechar como não clara.

Comment: A questão foi a curiosidade que tive ao ler esta resposta ainda mais quando vi este treixo: Use fixed-width integer types (in particular std::uint16_t instead of unsigned short and std::uint8_t instead of unsigned char), pois na definição esta exatamente igual

Answer (score 6):

A diferença entre um array em C e um `std::array` é basicamente a interface dele. O `std::array` tem uma interface de container (como `std::vector`, por exemplo), então tu tem um série de facilidades, como saber o tamanho do array, poder usar em algoritmos da STL (já que possui `begin` e `end`), verificação de limites, e também se no futuro precisar trocar para um container de alocação dinâmica é só trocar para o `std::vector` e todo teu código vai funcionar como antes. Por fim, em termos de performance os dois devem ter o mesmo desempenho.

Quanto ao `typedef`, ele apenas cria um "apelido" para o tipo, mas no fim é o mesmo tipo. Geralmente é usado para dar significado ao tipo. Mas prefira o `using` que é o equivalente em C++. `typedef` existe somente para compatibilidade com o C.

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE; // C
using BYTE = unsigned char; // C++
```