# Significado do array de char

Tags: array, c++, char, c++11

Estou tentando fazer o porte de um programa feito em C para C++ e existe uma declaração de um *array* de `char` que não compreendi.

Encontrei o seguinte:

```
char *matches[1+4];
```

Se fosse o seguinte:

```
char *matches[5];
```

Há diferença nessas duas declarações?

Comment: Se vai portar como deve de ser tem de mudar quase tudo como o @Maniero disse. Arrays de char como está nesse troço de dificilmente faz sentido em c++ quando pode usar `std::string`. O motivo de estar 4+1 e não 5 é porque se quer dar a ideia que são 4 chars mais o terminador, e por isso fica mais claro em termos de leitura do código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, elas são iguais, em C ou C++.

Mas elas são declarações de *array* em C, já em C++ deveria ser completamente diferente. Se realmente vai portar para C++ tem que mudar tudo. Caso contrário estará programando em C no compilador do C++.

Não faço ideia porque a pessoa fez uma soma e não colocou o valor 5 logo. Dá para fazer especulações, como fizeram aqui, mas são todas sem sentido (só a pessoa que fez pode explicar, e talvez nem ela, muitas vezes as pessoas fazem coisas que não entendem). Ele pode inclusive ter confundido com terminador, mas neste caso nem faz sentido, porque o *array* é 5 ponteiros para textos que terão o terminador, sequer tem o tamanho deles.

Você poderia fazer isto:

```
array<string, 5> matches;
```

Mas a maioria das pessoas já vão aproveitar e fazer:

```
vector<string> matches;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/Declaration.cpp).

Na maioria dos casos é tão ou mais adequado.

Você pode fazer como no original, funciona, mas saiba que não está portando para C++, são duas linguagens bem diferentes, a questão é que o compilador de C++ compila quase todos os códigos de C, então as pessoas acham que é a mesma coisa, se quer portar para C++ os códigos acima são os candidatos mais prováveis.

Veja mais em [Diferença entre std::list, std::vector e std::array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101).

Answer (score 0):

Além das diferenças para os tipos de dados do C++ - em que há arrays "de verdade", ao contrário de C, focando na sua dúvida específicas:

```
char *matches[1+4];

char *matches[5];
```

São equivalente em C?
Sim - são. O motivo do autor do código ter escrito da primeira forma muito provavelmente é pra ficar mais legível que ele quer espaço para 4 caracteres e mais 1 byte que é o terminador de string (que é `\x00`).

Para efeitos de código é exatamente a mesma coisa, inclusive a maior parte dos compiladores vai fazer a soma em tempo de compilação - os binários para as duas versões devem ser idênticos. É só realmente para o autor bater o olho e saber "ah, nessa variável cabem 4 caracteres como uma string".

Isso não é uma prática muito difundida, e não sei se eu recomendaria - de qualquer forma é apenas estética.

Answer (score 0):

As duas declarações são idênticas, e declaram um array de 5 ponteiros.

A forma que usa "1+4" é provavelmente um equívoco (sem maiores consequências) porque dá a impressão de que está deixando explícita a posição do zero binário que termina as strings em C, o que não faz sentido nessa declaração porque o que está sendo declarado não é uma string, e sim um array de ponteiros.

Quanto ao porte em si acho que inicialmente deve ser mexido o mínimo possível, só posteriormente quando a aplicação portada já estiver funcionando corretamente é que poderiam ser investigados os pontos onde poderia ser feita a mudança para C++ idiomático, isto é, trocar "char []" por string, utilizar os containers e algoritmos da STL, etc.