# Problema com posições vizinhas em arrays em C++

Tags: c, c++, algoritmo, loop

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int myVector[] = {2,6,4,1,9,5,7,3,8,0};
    int tamanhoVetor = sizeof(myVector)/sizeof(myVector[0]);

    //Imprime
    for (int i=0; i<tamanhoVetor-1; i++){
        cout << myVector[i+1] << ", ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

O esperado seria:

> 6, 1, 5, 3, 0

mas ele retorna:

> 6, 4, 1, 9, 5, 7, 3, 8, 0

Não entendi o porque que ele ocorre isso, eu tentei fazer a mesma coisa em Python, só que ocorre o mesmo problema. Provavelmente o erro está na minha lógica.

Comment: A variável tamanhoVetor está com o valor 10, seu for começo em 0 e sempre efetua a impressão do loop mais um, logo você acaba imprimindo todos os valores do seu vetor, com exceção da primeira posição.

Comment: Se você deseja pular números no for, você pode aumentar o incremento do mesmo, aumento por exemplo dois a cada ciclo:   for (int i=0; i<tamanhoVetor-1; i+=2)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Uma pena estar usando C em um código C++, não deveria fazer isto. Em C++ se usar [`array` ou `vector`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101) e não o ponteiro que simula *array* do C. Se fizesse C++ não teria esse erro.

Realmente sua lógica está errada, você deve pular de 2 em 2 e não pular de 2 em 1 e somar 1 como fez, e simplificando ficaria assim:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int myVector[] = {2,6,4,1,9,5,7,3,8,0};
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(myVector) / sizeof(myVector[0]); i += 2) cout << myVector[i+1] << ", ";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OZwmhr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/StepTwocpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/StepTwo.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é incrementar antes da impressão. A operação de adição dentro do vetor não funcionou. 
Conforme abaixo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int myVector[] = {2,6,4,1,9,5,7,3,8,0};
    int tamanhoVetor = sizeof(myVector)/sizeof(myVector[0]);

    //Imprime
    for (int i=0; i<tamanhoVetor-1; i++){
        i++;
        cout << myVector[i] << ", ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```