# Como remover um objeto de uma lista encadeada pelo valor do atributo em C++?

Tags: c++, lista, lista-encadeada

Qual é a melhor forma de remover um elemento de uma [lista](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) pelo valor do seu atributo, sem saber exatamente a sua posição?

Percebi que o método [erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) remove pela posição, e tentei utilizar junto com o método [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/), mas
eu não consegui compreender como manipular o retorno, e nem como passar os parâmetros corretamente.

Um exemplo de estrutura do objeto:

```
class Tipo{
    public:
        int id; // Esse valor é único para cada objeto
        float valor;
}
```

Minha tentativa:

```
void remove_by_id(list<Tipo>& lsita, int id){

    // Essa linha não funciona pois o método find deveria receber o objeto e não o atributo (eu acho)
    lista.erase( find(lista.begin(), lista.end(), id) );
}


list<Tipo> minha_lista = {...}; // Lista com n elementos

remove_by_id(minha_lista, 3); // Remover o objeto que tem id == 3
```

Comment: É possível, mas talvez seja o caso de usar uma lista ligada em vez de um vetor. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101

Comment: Ok, eu vou modificar a pergunta, porque eu também não saberia como fazer em uma lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível fazer isso implementando um operador de `Tipo` para `int`, ou polimorfismo com um tipo de proxy para IDs herdado por `Tipo`, ou um construtor para `Tipo` que recebe `int` e faz a conversão implícita. Porém, acredito que a solução mais simples seja utilizar uma higher-order function.

```cpp
auto remove_by_id(std::list<Tipo>& lista, int id)
{
    return lista.remove_if([&id](Tipo t) -> bool {
     return t.id == id; 
    });
}
```