# Diferença entre a inicialização de arrays de strings em C++

Tags: array, c++, string, ponteiro, estilo-de-codificação

Estou fazendo alguns desafios para praticar C++ e gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre as inicializações de *array* de *strings* abaixo:

```
const char *arr[3] = {"pedra", "papel", "tesoura"}; // Inicialização com ponteiros

const string arr[3] = {"pedra", "papel", "tesoura"};
```

As duas inicializações funcionam, porém gostaria de saber se existe algum problema em alguma delas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O primeiro é o jeito de se fazer em C, então ele apenas está criando um *array* de C que não é bem um *array* de verdade, e os elementos que vão dentro dentro são ponteiros para caracteres, portanto você terá que lidar com isso manualmente, terá que aplicar memória, pegar o ponteiro e colocar ali, e tratar tudo livremente e com muito cuidado, principalmente para liberar memória.

Mesmo sendo algo de C funciona em C++, mas não é recomendado na maioria das situações. Ele pode ser útil para interagir com código em C ou alguma otimização extrema que deseja fazer.

O segundo está meio C e meio C++. O tipo [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) lida com objetos de textos por você, ele faz a alocação e liberação de memória e tem métodos para manipular esses textos de forma fácil e robusta, é bem melhor que usar `char *` em quase todas situações.

Mas ele peca em usar um *array* do C quando deveria usar um [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) ou [outra estrutura mais fácil e robusta do C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101). O ideal seria fazer algo assim:

```
vector<string> arr =  {"pedra", "papel", "tesoura"};
```

Ou com, [`array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) para ficar com semântica igual, mas não é necessário na maioria dos casos.

```
array<string, 3> arr =  {"pedra", "papel", "tesoura"};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/Basic.cpp).

Se ainda quiser mais sobre o uso das formas em C dê uma pesquisada aqui. Sobre o C++ também tem bastante informação.

[Muita gente boa concorda com a ideia de que C++ deve ser escrito como C++](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/294) até que tenha um bom motivo para usar o que veio do C, especialmente acontece com `vector`.